# react-grid-layout with typescript not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-grid-layout

I have a new project and i try to use react-grid-layout for building a dashboard. unfortunately i am not able to get it to work.

I use:

`"@types/react-grid-layout": "0.16.5"
"react-grid-layout": "0.16.5"`

when i try to use it in a tsx file with

```
import { ReactGridLayout } from 'react-grid-layout';
```

i get the error:

> /node_modules/@types/react-grid-layout/index"' has no exported member 'ReactGridLayout'.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

## Update

Additional Info: I use it in an SPA Webapp which runs on .Net core 2.1
How I try to use it:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import ReactGridLayout, { Layout } from 'react-grid-layout';
 //const ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');
 export class Dashboard extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
    //ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');`
    public render() {
        //const ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');
        var layout = [
            { i: 'a', x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, static: true },
            { i: 'b', x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2, minW: 2, maxW: 4 },
            { i: 'c', x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 }
        ];
    return <div>
             <ReactGridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={30} width={1200}>`
                <div key="a">a</div>
                <div key="b">b</div>
                <div key="c">c</div>
            </ReactGridLayout>`
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally I made it work with the following steps found in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/8
Long story short: 
Add `"esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` to your tsconfig.json file. After that all worked like a charm.
Hope that helps if someone else has problems like that in a .net core react app.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the same named imports works in JavaScript but not works in TypeScript. Try with require, it worked for me.

```js
const ReactGridLayout = require('react-grid-layout');
```

I have a working example with TypesScript
https://codesandbox.io/s/5x5nyjqjwl

Comment: I tried different places for the require, but unfortunately none of them worked. probably I made something wrong. I updated my question with code how I try to use it.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example, hope it helps.

Comment: It seems that it would work but webpack throws an error when building it. The Webapp starts but shows an overlay message with the error: ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Dashboard.tsx:23:15 
    TS2604: JSX element type 'ReactGridLayout' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Comment: Additional Info: I use it in a .Net core 2.1 Webapplication based on the standard .Net Core 2.0 Rect template

Comment: Hope you cope with the new problem. I do not know your setup. I got to sleep, its night here.

Comment: I got around all with some settings in the tsconfig.json file. But thanks for your help anyways.